# Ionic App On Android Tablet

Tags: android, google-play, ionic-framework

I've just publish my app to the Google Play store for beta testing, but I can't install it on my Android tablet. The app will not install on my Samsung Galaxy Tab 10 tablet Model number GT-P5113 Android version 4.2.2, but it installs on my Samsung S5 mobile phone with no problem.

When I try to install the app from the Google Play Store it says that its designed for phones and the message is "Your device isn't compatible with this version'. I've checked the 'DEVICE COMPATIBILITY' section and my tablet version is checked.

I have this in my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true"       
 android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" 
 android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Can someone tell me how to make my app compatible with Android and iOS tablets? Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

Here's the complete AndroidManifest.xml.

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
 <manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="6" android:versionName="0.0.0.0" package="com.myapp.app" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="RsgApp" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
</application>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

Comment: Please post the rest of your manifest, notably things like `<uses-feature>`, `<uses-sdk>`, and `<uses-permission>`. Also, your Android app manifest, and the issues with the Play Store, have nothing to do with your compatibility with iOS tablets. If you are encountering problems with iOS compatibility, ask a separate question with the appropriate tags.

Comment: Check minSdkVersion & targetSdkVersion

Answer (score 0):

It is probably your min-sdk attribute.  If it is set to 21 (android 5.0), then it will only work on devices with Android v5.0.  Your min-sdk needs to be set to API level 17.  It could also be an issue with compatibility libraries (if you used widgets only available in later versions of android) and/or themes.  [This](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) page has more information about the  tag, and a little bit about Google Play Filtering.

Comment: Thanks, for the link. I will change the min-sdk attribute to see if it works, but my phone is v4.4.4 and I have no problem installing on it. The tablet version is Android version 4.2.2, API 17 and I have the min-sdk attribute set to 16.

Answer (score 0):

It's the camera auto focus feature:

```
uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
```

I have the same issue with Samsung SM-T110 (Tab 3 Lite);
it does not have camera autofocus so gets excluded from compatible devices.

Still trying to figure out how to remove this from the auto-generated manifest file tho, but hope this sets you in the right direction...