# Why is Cordova app incompatible with device?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing an hybrid app using Ionic Framework. The app works fine and I have published it to app store which I did not exclude any device from it.

Recently I bought a very cheap brand 7 inch tablet PC running on Android 4.4.2. I am able to build and install directly into the tablet. The app works fine on it. But why is that when I check on Google play store, I can't see my app listing from that device. When I try to access my app from browser, the app store says "This app is incompatible with your device".

Why is it incompatible as the app works fine when I manually install to it? How can I get my app listed on the device? What are the settings can I change?

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="5" android:versionName="0.0.5" package="com.company.appname" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.company.appname.MESSAGE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/fb_app_id" />
        <activity android:label="@string/fb_app_name" android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <activity android:label="@string/multi_app_name" android:name="com.synconset.MultiImageChooserActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light" />
        <receiver android:name="com.pushbots.google.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.company.appname" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.pushbots.plugin.PushHandler" />
        <receiver android:name="com.pushbots.push.DefaultPushHandler" />
        <service android:name="com.pushbots.push.GCMIntentService" />
        <activity android:name="org.cloudsky.cordovaPlugins.ZBarScannerActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" />
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <permission android:name="com.company.appname.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.company.appname.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Post the relevant sections of your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: @DheerajV.S. I have add my `AndroidManifest.xml`. Please help take a look. Thank you.

Comment: Don't use the package name com.company.appname in your manifest and don't use that package name for signing. Most likely someone else is using that package name already. I am surprised the google play developer console even allowed you to upload something like that. Your manifest is a huge mess I am afraid. Tell us what your app actually does. This way, we can tell you what can be removed. Did you register your app with c2dm (Google's cloud to device messaging)? Are you even using the facebook sdk? If so, did you register your app with Facebook? Is your app using a barcode scanner? gps?

Comment: I'd also remove this entire line. "<supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />"

Comment: This was posted for similar issue
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29111668/ionic-app-on-android-tablet